# PicklesDoc: How do I create a level 3 header

Tags: markdown, bdd, specflow

In order to create a level 3 header in [Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics/) symbols `###` should be used at the start of a line:

```
### That is my level 3 header
```

But Specflow comments lines started from `#` so no header is displayed in result. Is there any other way to render the level 3 header in [PicklesDoc](http://www.picklesdoc.com/#!index.md)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the "#" signs are swallowed by the SpecFlow/gherkin parser, so they are never passed to the Markdown parser. So there is - as far as I know - no way to create a level 3 header.

I am in the process of evaluating the upcoming Gherkin3 parser, maybe that parser will behave "better" in this regard.